# Disabling highlighting of menu items when using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, menu-bar

Whenever I use a keyboard shortcut that is accessible using the menu bar, the related item gets highlighted in blue for less than a second - which I find visually annoying.

Can one disable that effect?

Comment: A similar question at Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/439951

Comment: Thank you, changing the selection color was an acceptable solution for me!